# List of binary numbers: How many positions have a one and zero

Tags: python, numba

I have a list of integers, e.g. `i=[1,7,3,1,5]` which I first transform to a list of the respective binary representations of length `L`, e.g. `b=["001","111","011","001","101"]` with `L=3`.

Now I want to compute at how many of the `L` positions in the binary representation there is a `1` as well as a zero `0`. In my example the result would be `return=2` since there is always a `1` in the third (last) position for these entries. I want to compute this inside a function with a numba decorator.
Currently my code is:

```
@nb.njit
def count_mixed_bits_v2(lst):
    andnumber = lst[0] & lst[1]
    ornumber = lst[0] | lst[1]
    for i in range(1, len(lst)-1):
        andnumber = andnumber & lst[i+1]
        ornumber = ornumber | lst[i+1]
    xornumber = andnumber ^ ornumber
    result = 0
    while xornumber > 0:
       result += xornumber & 1
       xornumber = xornumber >> 1
    return result
```

First I take the AND of all numbers, ans also the OR of all numbers, then the XOR of those two results will have a 1 where the condition is fulfilled. In the end I count the number of 1's in the binary representation. My code seems a bit lengthy and I'm wondering if it could be more efficient as well. Thanks for any comment!

Edit: Without the numba decorator the following function works:

```
def count_mixed_bits(lst):
    xor = reduce(and_, lst) ^ reduce(or_, lst)
    return bin(xor).count("1")
```

(Credit to trincot)

Comment: Please do not edit the question after you have received an answer, it is against the [rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I've not changed my initial question, but was asked to compare the execution time of the solutions. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Against *which* of those rules exactly?

Comment: @StefanPochmann The rule is that everyone that sees the question and the answer should see the same question that the person who answered did.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I'd like to read that rule for myself. Where exactly on that page do you see it?

Comment: "**Do not change the code in the question** after receiving an answer." seems to apply here. Adding the timing code (and generally all the changes, including revision 2) seem to fall under that.

Comment: @Vogel612 Doesn't "the code" refer to the code to be reviewed (which didn't change at all)? And isn't it to avoid negatively affecting answers (which it didn't at all)? To me it seemed perfectly fine and useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know numba, but here's a little rewrite:

- Shorter variable names like `and_`, using the underscore as suggested [by PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) (*"used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword"*) and as done by [`operator.and_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.and_).
- Yours crashes if the list has fewer than two elements, I start with neutral values instead.
- Looping over the list elements rather than the indexes.
- Using [augmented assignments](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) like `&=`.
- In the result loop, drop the last 1-bit so you only have as many iterations as there are 1-bits.

```
def count_mixed_bits(lst):
    and_, or_ = ~0, 0
    for x in lst:
        and_ &= x
        or_ |= x
    xor_ = and_ ^ or_
    result = 0
    while xor_ > 0:
       result += 1
       xor_ &= xor_ - 1
    return result
```

Comment: Oh, this is indeed really fast!

Comment: @HighwayJohn What times do you get for the various solutions, and how are you measuring? Can you share your benchmark code?

Comment: Yes, let me make another edit. I think my current benchmark was flawed, since it compiled the numba function each time.

Comment: Unfortunately my benchmark comparison was deleted but your code is the fastest. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

I only see a few micro optimisations:

- Iterate the list instead of a range, so that you don't have to do another lookup with `list[i+1]`
- Use more assignment operators, such as `&=`, `|=` and `>>=`
- It is not needed to use `lst[1]` in `andnumber = lst[0] & lst[1]`. It can be just `andnumber = lst[0]`

So:

```
def count_mixed_bits_v2(lst):
    andnumber = ornumber = lst[0]
    for value in lst:
        andnumber &= value
        ornumber |= value
    xornumber = andnumber ^ ornumber
    result = 0
    while xornumber > 0:
       result += xornumber & 1
       xornumber >>= 1
    return result
```

This visits the first list value again (in the first iteration), even though it is not necessary. But that probably does not really hurt performance, and keeps the code simple.

Comment: I feel like `functools.reduce` might be more suited to the operations.

Comment: Yes, I had the same reaction before. The OP asked a previous question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801038/list-of-binary-numbers-how-many-positions-have-a-one-and-zero/64801528#64801528) where I answered like that, but apparently, that is not supported by numba, which only supports a subset of Python.

Comment: On https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html it says "The functools.reduce() function is supported but the initializer argument is required." But I could not get it to work.

Comment: So what did your `reduce` call look like? It should be like `reduce(and_, lst, lst[0])` then

Comment: @trincot Yeah, you are right.